# How much bytecodes does cobertura add to the source code?

Tags: methods, bytecode, instrumentation, cobertura

Cobertura uses Offline byte code instrumentation, which means it will add instructions after the compilation into the byte-code.
I have a very large generated method which now I'm trying to refactor. Itself is under 64KB JVM limitation, but after being added more byte code by cobertura, it will cause the oversize error. 
I'm asking this question to decide how to refactor the method generating logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround could be to just exclude your generated classes or specific methods from Cobertura instrumentation.

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: See excludeClasses in Cobertura documentation, as well as @CoverageIgnore annotation. https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference